# Avoiding duplicate column names when using create table as select

Tags: sql, hive, create-table

I'm currently trying to create a table, using CREATE Table AS SELECT statement. Within the SELECT statement there are currently joins over numerous tables (more than 10).

```
CREATE TABLE table_name AS 
    SELECT 
     * 
    FROM 
     table_x x
    LEFT JOIN 
     table_y y
     on x.id=y.fid 
    LEFT JOIN
     table_z z
     on x.id=z.fid
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Due to many of the tables sharing column names (though not data) I am getting a duplicate column name error.

I was wondering if there was a lazy way to generate column names, so there is no clash. For instance in the above example, `table_y` and `table_z` both have columns called `fid`.

I was wondering if there was a way to generate columns called `y.id` and `z.id`, or something similar (e.g. `y_id`,`z_id`) rather than just `id` and `id` in the new table?

I want to avoid writing a query where I have to explictly write out all the columns in the select, and us a `AS` statement as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name AS 
    SELECT 
     x.id as x_id,
     y.fid as y_fid,
     z.fid as z_fid,
     ...
     ...
     ...
    FROM 
     table_x x
    LEFT JOIN 
     table_y y
     on x.id=y.fid 
    LEFT JOIN
     table_z z
     on x.id=z.fid
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: best practice is to write out column names anyway as this protects you from having other queries, functions and procedures from breaking when underlying table structure changes, and makes the script much more maintainable - if a new developer has to make some changes they stand a much better chance of knowing what is being pulled in if it being stated in the script. You may even find there are some columns you don't need in the new table so you wouldn't need to select them

Comment: Part of this exercise is to sanity check the data being recorded over multiple tables, thus it is helpful for us to prefix each column with an identifier for each table. I fully understand I will have duplicate values across columns which are used for joining, however, this won't be used in a production environment and having duplicate content is not a big worry for this use case.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps, I'm missing something, but why do you want to select columns that essentially have the same values?

Instead of:

```
SELECT x.id as x_id, y.fid as y_fid, z.fid as z_fid, . . .
```

Why not just?

```
SELECT x.id as x_id, . . .
```

Is there a reason why you would want `NULL` values?  I could imagine flags indicating whether a match actually occurred, but there is no reason to include all columns just because they are there.

Comment: The purpose of the exercise is to sanity check the data, but to also denormalize the data (over multiple tables, into one table) which will then allow us to create multiple views based on the denormalised data. Increasing query speed and reducing the complexity of the SQL.

Comment: There are other columns which are not duplicated due to the joins, however, there are over 100 non-duplicated columns across the tables, so it would be useful not have to manually write each column name out explicitly. in the select statement, some of these column names do clash even though they represent different data. Thus it is useful to have table prefix the column.